# Azure function app stuck because of paging nextLink

Tags: azure, graph, azure-functions

I created an Azure function where I try to get all the AAD groupmembers. This timerjob needs to run once a day. When I do a test run I see in the logging it iterates a couple of time in the nextLink paging. But then it stuck without an error. I already increase the timeout to 10 minutes, but I still have the same problem.

When I run this script local on my machine it works fine. I expect it should iterate 127 times and get 12757 items.
[test run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pv9ld.png)

When I go to the monitor logging I dont see the session which was stuck.
[monitoring logging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOWAG.png)

```
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Timer)

"START"

$fileName = "Azure - ADGroupMembers.csv"

Write-Output "Connect to AAD"
Connect-AzAccount -identity

try {
    #region auth

   Write-Output "Get items from MS Graph"
   $token = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://graph.microsoft.com/").Token
   $authHeader = @{Authorization = "Bearer $token"}
    
    # #endregion
    
    # #region main proces

    $allPages = @()
    $items = (Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Get' -Uri 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$top=999&$expand=members' -Headers $authHeader  -ContentType 'Application/Json') 
    $allPages += $items.value

    $index = 0
    if ($items.'@odata.nextLink') {
            do {
                  $index++
                  "Index counter: $index"

                  $token = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://graph.microsoft.com/").Token
                  $authHeader = @{Authorization = "Bearer $token"}

                  $items = (Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Get' -Uri $items.'@odata.nextLink' -Headers $authHeader  -ContentType 'Application/Json')
                  $allPages += $items.value
             } until (
                 !$items.'@odata.nextLink'
             )
    }

    $items = $allPages
    "Count items: " + $items.Count

    $filePath = "D:\home\data\$($fileName)"

    Write-Host "Convert to csv to path '$($filePath)'" -ForegroundColor green
    $items | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $filePath
    
    
    #endregion
}
catch {
     write-output $_.Exception.Message
}

"FINISH"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to premium plan and now it works fine. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan?tabs=portal

Answer (score 0):

Try creating Azure Function app with Premium or Dedicated plan for the dedicated disk storage in your Function, As consumption app will only create a Function instance for the time your Function is running.

Function app consumption based plan also has a default time out of 5 minutes. Refer this **[MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#timeout)** for the same:-

I made some changes to your code and utilized Client Credentials flow with some try catch error blocks to get logging and the code succeeded, Refer below:-

**`run.ps1:-`**

```
# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Timer)

Write-Output "START"

# Function to fetch AAD group members and handle pagination
function Get-AADGroupMembers {
    param (
        [string]$Uri,
        [hashtable]$Headers
    )

    $allPages = @()

    do {
        $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Get' -Uri $Uri -Headers $Headers -ContentType 'Application/Json'

        $allPages += $response.value

        if ($response.'@odata.nextLink') {
            # Add a delay to handle rate limiting (adjust the duration as needed)
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 2

            $Uri = $response.'@odata.nextLink'
        }
        else {
            $Uri = $null
        }

    } while ($Uri)

    return $allPages
}

try {
    # Connect to Azure AD
    Write-Output "Connect to AAD"
    $SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "xxxxxxxa~N63RzmH34duL" -AsPlainText -Force
    $TenantId = '8xxxxxx9ed-afxxxxx5'
    $ApplicationId = 'cxxx45b5-b8xxxx1435cb'
    $Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $ApplicationId, $SecurePassword
    Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $TenantId -Credential $Credential

    # Get access token
    $token = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://graph.microsoft.com/").Token
    $authHeader = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $token" }

    # Get AAD group members
    $graphUri = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$top=999&$expand=members'
    $groupMembers = Get-AADGroupMembers -Uri $graphUri -Headers $authHeader

    Write-Output "Count of items: $($groupMembers.Count)"

    $filePath = "C:\home\data\Azure-ADGroupMembers.csv"

    Write-Output "Convert to CSV to path '$($filePath)'" -ForegroundColor green
    $groupMembers | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $filePath

    Write-Output "FINISH"
}
catch {
    # Log detailed error information
    Write-Error "Error: $_"
    Write-Output $_.Exception.Message
    Write-Output $_.Exception.StackTrace
}
```

Also, I changed the filePath to **`C:\`** instead of **`D:\`** as that is where my ***Azure Function Files are stored***, Refer the ***Kudu image*** below:-

[image]

***Output:-***

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it working in your tenant? And how many iteration (paging) did you get?

Comment: I already use premium and have the same problem

Comment: I received all the groups in the csv file

Comment: How many iteration did you get?